# barcode reading with mobile camera in python django

Tags: django

I am trying to access mobile camera for bar code scanner for a project in python django and connect to mssql server. In which way I can use this. Anybody can guide me. I have tried Quagga and jquery. But it is not working.

help in python django

Comment: Can you share your current attempt?

Comment: I tried Quagga. But camera open button is not functioning